# Getting the input level of microphone in windows IOT Core UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to get the actual input volume of a microphone while not recording.

My point is to start recording when sound go up some limit for a while.
I've found the NAudio nuget but it seems that's the wavein class dont exist in UWP.
How can i get the actual input volume of a microphone in c# whitout recording ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. Did you find anything?

If not, you can check this link

Windows IoT Core : Sensing Sound Levels
https://blog.falafel.com/windows-iot-core-sensing-sound/

It uses following components
1) Electret Microphone Amplifier – MAX9814 with Auto Gain Control
2) MCP3008 – 8 Channel 10-Bit ADC with SPI Interface
3) Pi Cobbler Plus
4) Your existing Raspberry Pi – Windows IoT Core Setup

In case if the above doesn't work try this Youtube URL and it might give you some hint to find the actual code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3Wt4xpkBYk

I have tried and tested the code as is in my project and it worked. Although there is hardware dependency such as you may need amplifiers to make it accurate otherwise small sounds doesn't work But then amplifiers need to be handled well otherwise smallest sounds make huge difference on the bar. I am trying to modify this to work with any USB microphone or computer so that I don't have to rely on mentioned hardware.